# getJSON returns undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I want to get the latitude and longitude from the returning JSON format but it returns me undefined

this is my code so far , the json format please have a look at the URL what exactly returns

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Garibaldi,Prishtina&sensor=true",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

        $.each(data, function () {
            $.each(this, function (key, value) {
                switch (key) {

                    case "lat":
                        alert(value) // access to this node works fine                      
                        break;

                    default:
                        alert(value[0].geometry.location.lat) // this is undefined
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: You should add the expected data structure instead of referring to a URL.

Comment: what do you get when you console.log(data); inside the success function?

Comment: Why `value[0]`? shouldn't it be `value.geometry...`?

Comment: Yes Martin u r right it works for me without [0]

alert(value.geometry.location.lat) this works,
Please add ur answer so i can accept as right answer...

Comment: @Martin That's the reason why; write it as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just...

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Garibaldi,Prishtina&sensor=true",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
       var loc = data.results[0].geometry.location;
       alert(loc.lat);
       alert(loc.lng);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am sorry that i cant give you the right answer as Martin answered first but ur way i think its better

Comment: It is my understanding that you are allowed to change the accepted answer, if you think a new answer is better.... :)  Im not saying you should....just saying its possible.....http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon

Answer (score 2):

You should use `value.geometry...` instead of `value[0]`.
Indices are not used inside a `$.each` loop.